# How can I upload data containing DateTime and Boolean values into Exact Target Data Extension

Tags: soap-api, .net, dataextensions

I have written .NET code to upload data into Exact Target Data Extension. My Data Extension contains multiple fields of types Text, Number, Boolean, Date. How can I upload the data with Date and Boolean values using Exact Target SOAP Client?

In my below code, I can only assign value of type string to deo.Properties[0].Value.

```
        DataExtensionObject deo = new DataExtensionObject();
        deo.CustomerKey = "MyDateExtensionName";
        deo.Properties = new APIProperty[1];

        DateTime dtBirthday = DateTime.Now;

        deo.Properties[0] = new APIProperty();
        deo.Properties[0].Name = "Birthday";
        deo.Properties[0].Value = dtBirthday; // This line will throw .NET Compilation error Cannnot assign DateTime to string

        //or

        deo.Properties[0].Value = dtBirthday.ToString(); // If I convert to string soapClient.Update call will return "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" error
```